# Switching to Doctrine: how to realize such query?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I had a TaskManager builded on flat PHP, and now I want to build it on Symfony.

I had such query string to fill TasksTable for the current day:

```
 (SELECT id, name, description, time, length
                           FROM daily 
                           WHERE 
                           (day = DAYNAME(:date)
                           OR day = 'all' 
                           OR (DAYNAME(:date) IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND day = 'weekend' )
                           OR (DAYNAME(:date) NOT IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND day = 'workday' ))
                           AND time IS NOT NULL)
                           UNION
                           (SELECT id, name, description,
                           DATE_FORMAT(date, '%H:%i') as time, length
                           FROM events
                           WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = :date)
                           ORDER BY time
```

As you see, it gets daily tasks for the current weekday (and for workday/weekend) and events for the current day.
Now I have two Doctrine entities - DailyTask and Event, with two appropriate tables and I want to convert this query to DQL to get an array with DailyTasks and Events as the query's result.

The problem - such trick doesn't work:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery("(SELECT id, name, description, time, length
                           FROM OrganizerBundle:DailyTask 
                           WHERE 
                           (day = DAYNAME(:date)
                           OR day = 'all' 
                           OR (DAYNAME(:date) IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND day = 'weekend' )
                           OR (DAYNAME(:date) NOT IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND day = 'workday' ))
                           AND time IS NOT NULL)
                           UNION
                           (SELECT id, name, description,
                           DATE_FORMAT(date, '%H:%i') as time, length
                           FROM OrganizerBundle:Event
                           WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = :date)
                           ORDER BY time")->setParameter('date', $day);
```

As far as I see, Doctrine doesn't support such Union (it simply shows error for leading parenthesis '(' ), and seems like it has problems with parentheses at all (in nested OR conditions, etc).

What will be the best solution here? So far I don't see any advantages from using Doctrine :( - it just makes things difficult and causes me to use some solutions on PHP which could be made using MySQL engine (date formatting, conditions, ordering, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to move that into a subquery. That's effectively what you're already doing anyway by placing your `ORDER BY` outside the last `)`.

```sql
SELECT  -- notice how I simply put the SELECT statement outside
    * -- you're grabbing all of the unioned content.
FROM
(
    -- I cleared away your spare `()` from in here and re-indented for clarity.
    SELECT id, name, description, time, length
    FROM daily 
        WHERE (
                day = DAYNAME(:date)
                OR day = 'all'
                OR (DAYNAME(:date) IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND day = 'weekend' )
                OR (DAYNAME(:date) NOT IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND day = 'workday' )
            )
            AND time IS NOT NULL
UNION
    SELECT id, name, description, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%H:%i') as time, length
    FROM events
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = :date
) subqry -- This lets SQL know that all of the above 
         -- needs to be viewed as "one table"
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem with DQL specificity. I had to add user-defined function DATE_FORMAT and DAY_NAME for the first. Then I had to use two queries - for each Entity.